# How to count by group and restart counting at a certain value in R

Tags: r

I want to do a simple counting of rows grouped by id (PIZ). The counting should restart both at every new id (PIZ) and if the value of the column "Wert" exceeds 500.

this is the data:

```
> dput(head(Labor_Neutrophile_alle2, n = 20))
structure(list(PIZ = c("37190985", "37190985", "37190985", "37190985", 
"37190985", "37190985", "37190985", "37190985", "37190985", "30195566", 
"30195566", "30195566", "30195566", "30195566", "30195566", "30195566", 
"30195566", "30195566", "30195566", "30195566"), Datum = c(2019.98630136986, 
2019.97808219178, 2019.97534246575, 2019.96712328767, 2019.95616438356, 
2019.94794520548, 2019.94246575342, 2019.93698630137, 2019.93150684932, 
2019.94520547945, 2019.92876712329, 2019.9095890411, 2019.8904109589, 
2019.87123287671, 2019.85205479452, 2019.84931506849, 2019.84383561644, 
2019.84109589041, 2019.82191780822, 2019.81369863014), Parameter = c("Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut"), Wert = c(20, 190, 320, 830, 1450, 870, 
650, 1390, 1090, 1850, 1800, 1300, 400, 2800, 1360, 1200, 1510, 
770, 2300, 2010), Einheit = c("10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", 
"10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", 
"10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", 
"10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL"), Neutrophilie = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And my desired outcome would be:

```
> dput(head(Neutro, n = 20))
structure(list(...1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), PIZ = c(10941890, 10942071, 
11712886, 17089951, 17228870, 17250590, 17250590, 17250590, 17250590, 
17250590, 17250590, 17250590, 17250590, 17250590, 17250590, 17250590, 
17250590, 17250590, 17250590, 17250590), Datum = c(2019.189, 
2014.195, 2014.942, 2015.203, 2014.323, 2013.764, 2013.841, 2014.09, 
2014.115, 2014.134, 2014.156, 2014.189, 2014.192, 2014.195, 2014.197, 
2014.2, 2014.205, 2014.208, 2014.211, 2014.214), Parameter = c("Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", "Neutrophile absolut", 
"Neutrophile absolut"), Wert = c(4310, 5810, 3700, 3090, 3010, 
1620, 1370, 2410, 2120, 710, 60, 20, 90, 120, 230, 220, 190, 
180, 470, 1260), Einheit = c("10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", 
"10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", 
"10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", 
"10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL", "10^3/µL"), Neutrophilie = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Count = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried a couple of things but, ya...:

```
xxx <- Labor_Neutrophile_alle2 %>% 
   group_by(PIZ, Wert > 500) %>% 
   summarise(count=n())
```

Comment: Your output data have different ID numbers, Datum and Wert from your input data. Presumably this is a mistake?

Comment: Thanks Allan both for the solution and the comment. The output is a randomly self-created data set that shall only depict how the output should look like. But it seems it is unusual to show it with unrelated data. ok. My mistake, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this `dplyr` method. You group by `PIZ`, then add a dummy variable to split into new groups depending on whether `Wert` is greater than 500. Then you just produce an integer sequence in each subgroup.

Note that your desired outcome has completely different data from the input data - this is presumably a mistake.

```r
Labor_Neutrophile_alle2 %>%
  group_by(PIZ) %>%
  mutate(Count1 = cumsum(Wert > 500)) %>%
  group_by(PIZ, Count1) %>%
  mutate(Count = seq(n())) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(-c(Count1))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 7
#>    PIZ      Datum Parameter            Wert Einheit Neutrophilie Count
#>    <chr>    <dbl> <chr>               <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <int>
#>  1 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut    20 10^3/µL            0     1
#>  2 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut   190 10^3/µL            0     2
#>  3 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut   320 10^3/µL            0     3
#>  4 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut   830 10^3/µL            1     1
#>  5 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1450 10^3/µL            1     1
#>  6 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut   870 10^3/µL            1     1
#>  7 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut   650 10^3/µL            1     1
#>  8 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1390 10^3/µL            1     1
#>  9 37190985 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1090 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 10 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1850 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 11 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1800 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 12 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1300 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 13 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut   400 10^3/µL            0     2
#> 14 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  2800 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 15 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1360 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 16 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1200 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 17 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  1510 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 18 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut   770 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 19 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  2300 10^3/µL            1     1
#> 20 30195566 2020. Neutrophile absolut  2010 10^3/µL            1     1
```